# MongoEngine won't save default False value

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have defined a User model and added a `featured` field to it:

```
class User(Document):
    email = EmailField(required=True)
    featured = BooleanField(default=False, required=True)
```

Then I create a user from this model and save it:

```
user = User(email=email, featured=False)
user.save()
```

But even having a default value and required flag I don't see that field created in the db if the BooleanField is set to False. When I set it to True in model or when create the user, it creates it and saves proper True value to it.
I want this field to be always present on creation if it's False or True.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you running?  We have a passing test case for this very issue:

See: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/test_document.py#L2881-2893

Comment: It looks like my version of MongoEngine was quite old - 0.5.2. I have updated it to the latest one and now it works properly. Thanks!

Comment: I am having this issue too, and I'm on version `0.8.7`.  It's the exact same case, with a `BooleanField` that's both `required=True` and `default=False`.  When I create a new object without specifying a value, it doesn't save any value to the database for that field.  What could be wrong?